# What does the error "function must be overridden" mean in jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm new to testing and jest. I'm using it together with react testing library to test a react application.

Particularly, I'm trying to test a header button that is responsible for changing the language of the website. As I understand so far, it's better to test for the "results" of the action (the text in the desired language rendered on the screen) rather than for the "logic" (the state of the app changing), so that's what I'm trying to do.

The actual test is the following:

```
test('Changes language on click', () => {
  render( <BrowserRouter> <Header /> </BrowserRouter> )
  
  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('es-language-btn'))
  expect(screen.getByTestId('about-desktop-btn')).toHaveTextContent('Sobre mi')
})
```

And the error I'm getting is this:

```
setEnglishLanguage function must be overridden

      12 |     setDarkModeOn: (): void => {throw new Error('setDarkModeOn function must be overridden')},
      13 |     englishLanguage: false,
    > 14 |     setEnglishLanguage: (): void => {throw new Error('setEnglishLanguage function must be overridden')}
         |                                            ^
      15 | }
      16 |
      17 | const Context = createContext <ContextInterface>(defaultState)
```

`setEnglishLanguage` is the function responsible of the state change the button triggers, but I don't know what overriding it means or how should I do it.

Comment: That error looks like it's from the default value of your context. So it looks like you (or whoever wrote this code) left a reminder to yourself that you need to render a context provider instead of using the default. Your test will need to render the context provider, or mock it out. I'm not familiar enough with jest + react context, so I can't provide a full solution for how to mock it.

Comment: That solved it, thanks! No way I could have figured that out by myself.